# trouble with .htaccess authorizations

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, lamp, .htpasswd

I have a Raspbian LAMP web server just for experimentation and I wanted to lock the main page with .htaccess.
It does not work as it should. It will read the first line "AuthTyper Basic" and lock the page but nothing more after that. The "AuthName" don't show up on the login pop-up. and the username and password do not work.
What am I doing wrong?

- Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian)

## apache2.conf

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>


# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

## .htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

## .htpasswd

```
admin:blah
```

I have tested the directories 100times in the .htaccess and they should be correct. I would like to know why this always happens. I have had a lot of trouble with .htaccess authorizations before.

## Edit

I reinstalled the Raspbian and installed everything again. And it all works fine now. I have no idea why.

I did use the http://www.htaccesstools.com/ to make an encrypted password and the "blah" was just a placeholder. I forgot to say that in the post so that was my bad. :)

Comment: is `AuthUserFile` have correct path for password file?

Comment: As a side safety / security note, you should really use `/usr/bin/htpasswd` for generating your passwd files, instead of some third party site who doe not fully support https, and could potentially be stealing passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your password hashed(encrypted), not in a plain text format.

Try this:

```
admin:$apr1$yXIoHg6X$qSyhw3y90Szcjqf.N/F000
```

> Each line contains a username and a password separated by a colon ":".
>   You can not see the actual passwords as they are **hashed (encrypted)**
>   using a complex algorithm. The default algorithm is different from
>   platform to platform. On Windows the passwords are hashed using **MD5**,
>   and on Linux its based on a system function called “**crypt()**”.

[**Source**](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/htpasswd/)

What else you can do is, as commented, to check if `AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd` is correct, otherwise the content of **.htaccess** looks fine to me.

You can also check if you have **mod_auth_basic** module loaded, for example with the following script:

```
<pre>
<?php
    print_r (apache_get_modules(), true);
?>
</pre> 
// Sample output will contain all the loaded modules
Array
(
[0] => core
[1] => mod_win32
[2] => mpm_winnt
[3] => http_core
[4] => mod_so
[5] => mod_access_compat
[6] => mod_actions
[7] => mod_alias
[8] => mod_asis
[9] => mod_auth_basic <---- This is what we need
```

You can generate user and password in Linux environment with the following command:

```
htpasswd /var/www/html/.htpasswd admin
```

then you will be prompted to enter password.

> Creates a new file and stores a record in it for user admin. The user
>   is prompted for the password. If the file exists and cannot be read,
>   or cannot be written, it is not altered and htpasswd will display a
>   message and return an error status.

[**Source**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html)

You can also generate **.htpasswd** content via online tool:

- [www.htaccesstools.com](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)
- [www.web2generators.com](https://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator)
- [www.htpasswdgenerator.net](http://www.htpasswdgenerator.net/)
- [www.htpasswdgenerator.de](http://www.htpasswdgenerator.de/)
- [www.askapache.com](https://www.askapache.com/online-tools/htpasswd-generator/)

Comment: The "blah" was a more just a placeholder. I had an encrypted password that I generated from [link](http://www.htaccesstools.com/). Sry I didn't say that. :)

Comment: I'm glad that you got the idea. Good job mate :)